# How to get live output while processing images in ImageJ?

Tags: image-processing, imagej

All what I am describing here takes place in ImageJ 32-bit version(Java 1.6.0_20).The Plugin I am using to get the capture stream from the camera is Civil Capture.

I made it work that i get image slices in a stack from a live video capture stream, with a camera. Afterwords I process them, lets just say i feed the values of one horizontal line of pixels of one image in an array and than plot this line with the methods from Plot and Plot Window.

So now my Problem:
When I run my plugin it first captures the picture than it gets processed. Now a Window is beeing opend for the Image stack and one for the Plot.
For the next incoming image it will also be processed and the Plot is beeing updated. But only at the end, when as many images, as I want to, were processed, the Plot and the images will actually be displayed. While the processing is happening, both Windows are white and dont show anything.
Is it possible to make ImageJ display the plot and the images after the processing part? and how?

I have found the Dynamik Profiler but I didnt get it to work the way I wanted it to. Especally since you have to input a image and not an array.

This is my first question so dont be too hard on me if i missed to give you information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
So the problem was that the entier program took place in one thread. So to fix it, the ploting had to be done in a seperat thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`ImagePlus#updateAndDraw()`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html) to update the image display.

For the [`Plot` class](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/gui/Plot.html), use:

`Plot#show()`

to display it for the first time, and:

`Plot#updateImage()`

to update the plot window.

Comment: I guess you mean that instead of the "#"  i have to use a dot? becaus i get a message that the "#" is an illigal character. I am already using the methods you described (with "." and not "#"). I slowly think that that the live displaying of the image and the plot might not be possible in ImageJ

Comment: The `#` is used to indicate that the method is an *instance method* of that class: while `Plot.show()` won't work (because it is not *static*), it does work after you instantiated the class: `myPlot = new Plot(...)`, then `myPlot.show()`

Comment: Please mark this answer as a solution if it solved your question. Otherwise, please add a new answer describing how you solved your problem, instead of editing the original question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help!